# Drawing a dilation of a polygon with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to achieve the following picture in TikZ:

[image: a dilated polygon]

Of course, I just did this in TikZ, but I did it this way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,1) coordinate (A);
        \draw (1,1) coordinate (B);
        \draw (3,3) coordinate (C);
        \draw (3,4) coordinate (D);
        \draw (0,4) coordinate (E);
        \fill[fill=blue!30,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=20pt] ($(A)+(-20pt,-20pt)$) -- ($(B)+(8.284pt,-20pt)$) -- ($(C)+(20pt,-8.284pt)$) -- ($(D)+(20pt,20pt)$) -- ($(E)+(-20pt,20pt)$) -- cycle;
        \fill[fill=red!30,draw=red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I really want is to just specify the coordinates of the red polygon and then draw a dilated version of it with rounded corners. In the end this is to highlight certain areas in a graph.

Any ideas and hints are appreciated!

Comment: I'm an `asymptote` guy, so this may sound dumb.  Maybe you could... 1-define the red polygon, 2-draw the polygon with a large round black pen, 3-draw the polygon with a slightly smaller round blue pen, 4-fill the polygon with a red pen.

Comment: @James It doesn't sound dumb at all! That does the job for my purpose and is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct implementation in `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,1) coordinate (A) (1,1) coordinate (B) (3,3) coordinate (C)(3,4) coordinate (D) (0,4) coordinate (E);
  \draw[rounded corners, line width=40pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners, blue!30, line width=39pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;
  \draw[red, fill=red!30] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is James's idea implemented in Metapost (I use ConTeXt, but the same thing will work in LaTeX):

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=2mm]
  path p;
  p := (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (3,3) -- (3,4) -- (0,4) -- cycle;
  p := p scaled 1cm;

  path q ;
  q := p cornered 10pt;

  draw q withcolor blue
      withpen pencircle scaled 21pt;

  draw q withcolor 0.3[white, blue]
      withpen pencircle scaled 20pt;

  fill p withcolor 0.3[white, red];
  draw p withcolor red;


\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you draw path `p` with each of your draw commands?  I'm not sure why you need to define a path `q`.

Comment: @James: That would work as well. Defining a new path or now is just a matter of coding style. I could have used `draw p cornered 10pt withpen ... ` instead of `draw q ...`.

Comment: But are you sure you need the `cornered` path?  If the pen tip is round then you will automatically have rounded corners.

Comment: @James: interesting idea. I am not on my computer right now, but with a circular pen, the radius will be proportional to the dialation. One might want to use a smaller or a larger radius (as in the other answer)

Comment: @Aditya This could be solved with a rounded square shape pen. Not sure if Metapost and/or TikZ provide such.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
New, more simple solution with use of `transform canvas`:

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate                 (A) at (-1.5,-2);
\coordinate[above=4cm of A] (E);
\coordinate[right=3cm of E] (D);
\coordinate[below=1cm of D] (C);
\coordinate[right=1cm of A] (B);
%
\coordinate[right=2mm of B] (BC);
\coordinate[below=2mm of C] (CB);
%
\draw[draw=blue, fill=blue!30,thick,rounded corners=2mm,
      transform canvas={yscale=1.15,xscale=1.2}]
    (A) |- (D) -- (CB) -- (BC) --  cycle;
\draw[draw=red, fill=red!30] 
    (A) |- (D) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This depends on the fact that you chose `(A)` such that the transformation is central. Also, the distance between blue and red will not be the same for all edges this way.

Comment: exactly. better solution provide AmoAmmar, it is independent from transfromation ...